# How to Use Mica/Acrylic Backdrop with Tint Color?

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, backdrop

I want to use Mica/Acrylic with Tint Options. There are 2 ways to do this:

First one is available in WinUI3-Gallery and is working fine, however, it seems that there is a better (I don't know!) way to do this, in second option we can inherit `SystemBackdrop` class and override `TargetConnected` method:

```
public class SystemMica : SystemBackdrop
{
    private MicaController micaController;

    public SystemMica()
    {
        micaController = new MicaController();
    }

    protected override void OnTargetConnected(ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop connectedTarget, XamlRoot xamlRoot)
    {
        base.OnTargetConnected(connectedTarget, xamlRoot);

        // Set configuration.
        SystemBackdropConfiguration defaultConfig = GetDefaultSystemBackdropConfiguration(connectedTarget, xamlRoot);

        //micaController.TintColor = Colors.Yellow;
        micaController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(defaultConfig);
        
        // Add target.
        micaController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(connectedTarget);
    }

    protected override void OnTargetDisconnected(ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop disconnectedTarget)
    {
        base.OnTargetDisconnected(disconnectedTarget);

        micaController.RemoveSystemBackdropTarget(disconnectedTarget);
        micaController = null;
    }
}
```

If we run above code, we can see mica backdrop and changing Theme To Dark/Light is working fine!
However, when we add `TintColor`:

```
micaController.TintColor = Colors.Yellow;
```

and run our app, changing Theme does not reflect to backdrop and backdrop uses previous theme.
In ms-docs, it is mentioned that

> If FallbackColor, LuminosityOpacity, TintColor, or TintOpacity are modified by the material's implementation, changes to associated SystemBackdropConfiguration.Theme will no longer automatically toggle the controller's theme (because the default Dark and Light configurations are no longer appropriate). In this case, the material's appearance properties need to be manually updated to match the new theme in SystemBackdrop.OnDefaultSystemBackdropConfigurationChanged.

I tried this:

```
protected override void OnDefaultSystemBackdropConfigurationChanged(ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop target, XamlRoot xamlRoot)
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            SystemBackdropConfiguration defaultConfig = GetDefaultSystemBackdropConfiguration(target, xamlRoot);
            switch (((FrameworkElement)window?.Content).ActualTheme)
                {
                    case ElementTheme.Dark: defaultConfig.Theme = Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops.SystemBackdropTheme.Dark; break;
                    case ElementTheme.Light: defaultConfig.Theme = Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops.SystemBackdropTheme.Light; break;
                    case ElementTheme.Default: defaultConfig.Theme = Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops.SystemBackdropTheme.Default; break;
                }
            micaController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(defaultConfig);
        }
    }
```

but nothing is happening and it does not work!

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots to clearly describe what effect you want?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT i added a screenshot, when i change tintcolor in dark theme, it looks so bad, in colorpicker i can change alpha channel so when i change it, it looks better, so i am confused about tint color and dark/light theme, am i doing all stuff correctly? is this a normal behavior? i expect a tint color with different opacity when i use dark theme and i think this should be done automatically. (i know i can change tint opacity but i dont want to do this manually)

Comment: Could you please tell us when you change `tintcolor` in light theme, does the `tintopacity` change automatically? Whether it satisfies the effect you want in the light theme?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT yes in Light Theme everything is normal

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it seems an issue, I suggest you could post the issue to [the Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) for better help.